# Comparing and isolating the difference in 2 mp3 files

Tags: audio, comparison, mp3

I have an archive of old radio shows, and for each show I have 2 different mp3 files.

The first is a podcast version of the show, released by the station. This is a truncated version of the show with a lot of content cut out.

The second is a recording of the full show, as it was aired.

I would like to compare the two mp3 files for each show and isolate the bits from the full version that DON'T appear in the podcast version.

Does anyone know of any software capable of doing this?

I read that an abx comparator might be what I need, but I've watched a few video tutorials for the foobar abx comparator and I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: +1 Interesting question! I've not heard of such a tool, but am certainly interested in finding out if there is. You might be better off posting this question on a different forum though, Sound Design possibly?